# Can EAGLE CAD make square-ended traces?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, cad

Is there a way in EAGLE CAD (Version 7) to create "sharp" traces?

Here an image for better explanation:

[image]

The trace can be made wider. But if I increase the width, it looks something like this:

[image]

Which is not what I want. Rather I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think the first one looks better. It can be wider or it must be wider?

Comment: @PedroQuadros It can be wider.

Comment: I could have sworn that older version used to use octagonal apertures for traces...can't seem to find it or do that anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this two ways:

1. Position the wide trace's endpoint somewhere on the upper edge, not the middle, of the horizontal trace.  Then use a narrower trace to make a connection from the wide trace's endpoint to the midline of the horizontal trace.  The narrow connecting trace will be surrounded by copper, and so it's only there to make Eagle happy.

   Or,
2. Draw the wide trace as you have it shown in your second image.  Then, draw a polygon over the top of the wide trace, using the edges of the trace as guides.  Of course, don't draw the extended radius in the polygon :)  Assign the polygon to the same net name, then delete the original trace.

I can add pictures later today if this doesn't make sense. Please let me know.

Comment: hm.. so there is no real clean way of doing this in EAGLE?

Comment: @d3l Not that I've found.  Even Cadence OrCAD software has this same problem.  Or perhaps I simply haven't found the solution yet :)

Answer (score 3):

Make a small arc segment at the end of the line, then change its angle to 1° and the cap to flat. Now you can drag the 'sharp' end to a position inside the other line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using round apertures for drawing traces has an advantage, the actual width of the trace is independent of the angle of the trace. When using a square aperture instead, a trace with 45 ° is wider than a trace with 0 or 90 °.